# Why does `file_pointer{0}` compile but `file_pointer(0)` not?

Tags: c++, initialization

I have browsed SO regarding initializer lists and member initialization and haven't found an answer to this specific issue. Please excuse me if it does turn out to be a duplicate.

I'm browsing C++ source code where a member `FILE*` of a struct is initialized like so:

```
struct Something {
    FILE* d_fp{0};
}
```

I have Googled it, and I understand the concept of initialization using an initializer list constructor.

I understand that if no dedicated initializer-list constructor is present on the instantiated type, a different constructor with a matching number of arguments is called. So saying `MyType o{0}` is the same as `MyType o(0)`. Please correct me if my understanding is false.

However, in this case, changing the code to read `FILE* d_fp(0)` results in compiler errors:

```
main.cpp:47:11: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
   47 |     FILE* d_fp(0);
      |           ^~~~
      |               ;
main.cpp:47:16: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
   47 |     FILE* d_fp(0);
      |                ^
main.cpp:47:16: error: expected ')' before numeric constant
   47 |     FILE* d_fp(0);
      |               ~^
      |                )
```

So two questions follow:

1. Why does `d_fp(0)` not do the same thing as `d_fp{0}` in this case?
2. What might be the reason a programmer chooses `d_fp{0}` initialization instead of the more intuitive `d_fp = 0`? Is it simply a matter of taste, or is it not actually the same thing?

Comment: @AdrianMole `FILE* d_fp(0);` is not the MVP.  It would be legal and correct if it wasn't inside a class.  Inside a class, you can only use `{}` or `= ...` syntax to initialize a member.

Comment: @NathanOliver Fair comment. Just that I was a bit vexed by clang's message: **error : expected parameter declarator**. (Suggesting it sees the start of a function declaration at `d_dp(` but then doesn't get one.)

Comment: @AdrianMole Clang is saying that because in a class, the only thing that has a `()` after the name is a function, so that's what clang is expecting but not getting.

Comment: @NathanOliver OK - Then it's a *slightly* vexing parse. :)